# AndroidPlot: Support for graphing a dashed line

Tags: android, android-widget, graphing, androidplot

Are there line styles in the works for dashed lines, dotted lines, etc.?

I know you can add/remove the point by setting the vertexColor to null like in this example:

```
LineAndPointFormatter blueFormat = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(30,144,255), null, null);
```

however, I haven't been able to find a quick property setting like "setDottedLine(true)" or something to that extent in the [javadoc](http://androidplot.com/javadoc/0.5.1/com/androidplot/xy/LineAndPointFormatter.html).  I suppose I could graph every 10 points and drop every 10 while I'm parsing, but that might be a little more overhead than needed.

Is there a work around or a trick to create a dashed line using LineAndPointFormatter or by setting some other widget property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out..

There is a constructor for LineAndPointFormatter:

> **setLinePaint(Paint)**

So to draw a dashed line, you would then use a snippet like this:

```
Paint dashPaint = new Paint();
dashPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
dashPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
dashPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
dashPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {10,5}, 0));
LineAndPointFormatter redDash = new LineAndPointFormatter(dashPaint.getColor(), null, null);
redDash.setLinePaint(dashPaint);
plot.addSeries(red,redDash);
plot.redraw();
```